# Submit an app to Apple Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have done an IOS App without Xcode and now i want to submit it to the Apple Store.
I already have the distribution certificate, provisioning profile and the App details on "My apps" page. 
I know the next and last step is to "upload binaries" on Xcode, but can you tell me how exactly do i do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Best practice would be to follow Apple's guidelines. You can find them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html)

Comment: You wrote "without Xcode"... which IDE did you use to build your app? That will likely be useful information here.

Comment: You are rigth garrettmurray, i am sorry for not being cleared.
I have built my ios app with Adobe Air.

Answer (score -1):

You have to open your project in Xcode, and go to Product->Archive. That's all

Answer (score -1):

This is what I do when I submit an App for review.

1. Open XCode, change the scheme to "Generic iOS Device".
2. In the menu bar click "Product" > "Archive". Wait for Xcode to compile..
3. A new window will appear, select the new archive in the list and then click in the blue button at the right "Upload to App Store".
4. It will ask you for your provisioning profile from the list. Pick one and click "choose"
5. Click "Upload", wait for it to finish. It should be available in your developer.apple.com page.

Hope this helps.

For more detailed info check https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html